# Are there any Russian words, which changed the meaning through the intermediary language?

Tags: этимология

Are there any words which have started with one meaning, then got incorporated into another language while changing the meaning and then got reimported back with a different meaning?

Comment: Нет, про "бистро" оказалась лингвистическая байка

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such words do exist, but they are quite few, I know of only two, and even these are ultimately of Turkic origin.

> [Бирич](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biritch) (Old East Slavic 'herald') > English 'Bridge game' > Russian 'Игра «Бридж»'
>
> Балаклава (city name, from Crimean Tatar) > English 'balaclava' (a hat that covers the face) > Russian 'балаклава' (a hat that covers the face)

Answer (score 2):

Пишут что:

- `пищаль` стала `пистолем` и вернулась как `пистолет`.

  @shabunc указывает что "пищаль" была не русской, а чешской, вот и Фасмер об этом пишет:

  > Пистоле́т род. п. -а, впервые в 1689 r., при Петре I см. Христиани 34; диал. в знач. "карапуз", петерб. Через стар. нем. Pistolet (ХVI в.; см. Шульц–Баслер 2, 541) или непосредственно из франц. pistolet от ит. pistola. Романисты ищут источник этого слова в чеш. рišt᾽аl (см. пища́ль).

  <sup>Кстати "гаубица" также пришла из германии, но его прототипом была чешская "праща" houfnice.</sup>
- `хрип` вернулся как `грип`

  В комментах высказано сомнение по поводу грипа, вот цитата из Фасмера:

  > **грип**, Ближайшая этимология: из франц. grippe, которое в свою очередь из русск. хрип; см. Шухардт, SID. 69; Гамильшег, EW 492; Фасмер, Zschr. d. Wf. 9, 20; Клюге-ГеЁтце 217 и сл.

  В книге "Приключения слов" [утверждается](http://attic.su/articles/adventures-of-the-words/charter-4) что "хрип" сначала попал в немецкий:

  > грипп – не что иное, как онемеченное русское хрип. Это не так странно и случайно, как может показаться. Грипп – довольно неопределенная болезнь, которая проявляется то одними, то другими признаками, и имеет очень разнообразные формы. Поэтому той разновидности, которая пришла в Германию из России, могли дать название, образованное от русского хрип.
- `бЫстро` - фр. `bistro` - `бистрО`

  "Эхо войны" с Наполеоном в 1812 году: слово `бЫстро`, которым русские солдаты подгоняли официантов в парижских кафе превратилось в `бистрО` и уже из французского языка вернулось в русский.

  В комментах пишут что версия эта сомнительная. У Фасмера этого слова нет, зато в английском этимологическом [словаре](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bistro?s=t) пишут:

  > **bistro** 
  >   1922, from Fr. bistro (1884), originally Parisian slang for "little wineshop or restaurant," of unknown origin. Commonly said to be from Russian bee-stra "quickly," picked up during the Allied occupation of Paris in 1815 after the defeat of Napoleon; but this, however quaint, is unlikely. Another guess is that it is from bistraud "a little shepherd," a word of the Poitou dialect, from biste "goat."

  Т.е. происхождение неизвестно; версия про войну с Наполеоном популярная, но маловероятная. Более вероятно что слово происходит из диалектного bistraud - "маленький пастух" от biste - "козел".

Comment: про "грипп" - это точно народная этимология, вот прямо точно-точно - это от ср.-французского gripper - хватать.

Comment: про пистолет же я менее уверен, но насколько я могу помнить - тоже нет, есть версия, что произошло от чешского слова, родственного "пищали", но-таки не из русского.

Comment: @shabunc Фасмер утверждает что gripper происходит от хрип (добавил цитату в пост).